# How to implement basic CRUD features in one place using ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Consider that I have 3 entities:

- User
- Blog
- News

Each of them has these features:

- Read by ID
- Read by page
- Read by page with sorting
- Update with JSON Patch
- Delete by ID
- Delete entities created before...

The codes will be quite simple and duplicated, do I really have to implement these codes in every controller? I don't want to write code like:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Blog>> GetAll()
{
  return _context.Blogs.ToList();
}
```

once and once again.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you a lot. Basically you have to use Generic Repository pattern.

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        Task Add(T entity);
        Task Add(IEnumerable<T> entities);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Update(IEnumerable<T> entities);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Delete(IEnumerable<T> entities);
        Task<int> TotalItems(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, string includeProperties = "");
        Task<IList<T>> GetAll(
                            int pageNumber = 1,
                            int pageSize = 8,
                            bool isPaged = true,
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> serachFilter = null,
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
                            Expression<Func<T, T>> select = null,
                            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                            string includeProperties = "");

        Task<T> GetById(string Id);
        Task<IList<TType>> Select<TType>(Expression<Func<T, TType>> select = null) where TType : class;
    }

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }
    
    public Repository(TestStudyContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        DbSet = context.Set<T>();
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    
    public async Task Add(T entity) => await DbSet.AddAsync(AssignDefaultValueForAdd(entity: entity));
    public async Task Add(IEnumerable<T> entities) => await DbSet.AddRangeAsync(AssignDefaultValueForAdd(entities));
    
    public void Delete(T entity) => DbSet.Remove(entity: entity);
    public void Delete(IEnumerable<T> entities) => DbSet.RemoveRange(entities: entities);
    public async Task<T> GetById(string Id) => await DbSet.FindAsync(Id);
    public async Task<int> TotalItems(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = DbSet;
        foreach (var inlcudeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(inlcudeProperty);
        }
        if(filter != null)
            return await query.CountAsync(filter);
    
        return await query.CountAsync();
    }
    public void Update(T entity) =>  DbSet.Update(AssignDefaultValueForUpdate(AssignDefaultValueForAdd(entity: entity)));
    public void Update(IEnumerable<T> entities) => DbSet.UpdateRange(AssignDefaultValueForUpdate(entities: entities));
    public async Task<IList<TType>> Select<TType>(Expression<Func<T, TType>> select = null) where TType : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = DbSet;
        return await query.Select(select).ToListAsync();
    }
    
    public async Task<IList<T>> GetAll(
                        int pageNumber = 1,
                        int pageSize = 8,
                        bool isPaged = true,
                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> serachFilter = null,
                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
                        Expression<Func<T, T>> select = null,
                        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = DbSet;
    
    
        foreach (var inlcudeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            query = query.Include(inlcudeProperty);
    
        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);
    
        if (serachFilter != null)
            query = query.Where(serachFilter);
    
        if (orderBy != null)
            query = orderBy(query);
    
        if(select != null)
            query = query.Select(select);
        
        if(isPaged == true)
            return await query.AsNoTracking().Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync<T>();
    
        return await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync<T>();
    }
    
    
    
    #region Helper
    
    private T AssignDefaultValueForUpdate(T entity)
    {
        Type t = entity.GetType();
        var UpdatedOnInfo = t.GetProperty("UpdatedOn");
        if (UpdatedOnInfo != null)
            UpdatedOnInfo.SetValue(entity, DateTime.Now);
    
        return entity;
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<T> AssignDefaultValueForUpdate(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        var updatedEntities = new List<T>();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
            updatedEntities.Add(AssignDefaultValueForUpdate(entity));
        return updatedEntities;
    }
    
    private T AssignDefaultValueForAdd(T entity)
    {
        Type t = entity.GetType();
        var userInfo = t.GetProperty("UserId");
        if (userInfo != null)
            if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User != null)
            {
                var userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("UserId")?.Value;
                userInfo.SetValue(entity, userId);
            }
    
        var createdOnInfo = t.GetProperty("CreatedOn");
        if (createdOnInfo != null)
            createdOnInfo.SetValue(entity, DateTime.Now);
    
        var UpdatedOnInfo = t.GetProperty("UpdatedOn");
        if (UpdatedOnInfo != null)
            UpdatedOnInfo.SetValue(entity, DateTime.Now);
    
        return entity;
    }


    private IEnumerable<T> AssignDefaultValueForAdd(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        var updatedEntities = new List<T>();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
            updatedEntities.Add(AssignDefaultValueForAdd(entity));
        return updatedEntities;
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

Add following Line (Add Service) into the Startup.cs

```
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>), typeof(UnitOfWork<>));
```

In Controller Need to add following things for CRUD Opertion.

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork<Category> categoryContext;

    public CategoriesController(IUnitOfWork<Category> categoryContext)
    {
        this.categoryContext = categoryContext;
    }

    [HttpGet(ApiRoutes.Categories.GetAll)]
    public async Task<IList<CategoryViewModel>> GetAll()
    {
        var list = await categoryContext.Repository.GetAll(isPaged: false);
        return list;
    }


    [HttpPost(ApiRoutes.Categories.CreateAndUpdate)]
    public async Task<IList<Category>> CreateAndUpdate([FromBody] Category model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Id))
        {
            model.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            await categoryContext.Repository.Add(model);
        }
        else
        {
            categoryContext.Repository.Update(model);
        }
        await categoryContext.Commit();
        return await GetAll();
    }


    [HttpDelete(ApiRoutes.Categories.Delete)]
    public async Task<IList<Category>> Delete(string id)
    {
        var category = await categoryContext.Repository.GetById(id);
        categoryContext.Repository.Delete(category);
        await categoryContext.Commit();
        return await GetAll();
    }

}
```

Don't forgot to Use Unit of Work Pattern

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    IRepository<T> Repository { get; }
    Task Commit();
}

public class UnitOfWork<T> : IUnitOfWork<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly TestStudyContext context;
    public IRepository<T> Repository { get; }
    public UnitOfWork(
        TestStudyContext context,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.Repository = new Repository<T>(context, httpContextAccessor);
    }
    public async Task Commit() =>  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    private readonly bool Disposed = false;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.Disposed)
            if (disposing)
                context.Dispose();
    }
}
```